# Is there a dissection proof of the Pythagorean Theorem, such that a single cut makes the needed pieces from the squares?

Tags: proof-without-words

Can you cut the squares of a right triangle with one cut (cutting all three pieces at the same time) so that it’s possible to arrange them and prove Pythagoras’ theorem?

Comment: Thank you Blue for the title edit!

Answer (score 0):

Can we cut? **yes**
will it prove Pythagoras Theorem? **no**

Just take a **3-fold** paper (or 3 papers stacked together), and cut out a square ($3$ squares!)  from all papers **at once.**
Arrange them (squares) on $3$ sides of your **Right triangle**.

All $3$ are of same size?
Is it possible to have a **Right triangle** with  all sides equal?
 (so that their corresponding squares are cut equal?)
Forget about proving *Pythagoras Theorem*!

**Is there any other way to cut all $3$ squares together?**

Comment: This seems vague (to me).. I'd like to see a diagram.

Comment: @coffeemath sure, but how to i make and upload a diagram? please suggest an appropriate platform.

Comment: it is like we do in origami: make a handkerchief fold and cut out 4 similar circles out of it. Here we take 3 sheets of paper,one above other, and cut out squares from all of them at once.

Comment: Omega-- Personally I've not made any diagram here, so can't advise how.